# ExtJs Grid acting very strange

Tags: asp.net, extjs, grid

So I have two pictures of the weirdness that is occuring
[image]

As you can see in the picture above, the scroll bar on the right hand side is being cut off a little bit by the screen, and even when you scroll to the right, you don't get the bar back, it remains cut off.

Here is the other scenario:
[image]

Here, you can see that when I scroll down in this grid, the scroll bar kind of fits into the bottom of the grid and doesn't even go all the way down. You need to manually click into the grid and hit the down arrow to get the rest of the way down.

What could be causing both of these weird issues?

Edit:

Here is the code to generate the grid (Ext created through VB controls):

```
Dim VehicleOptionsGrid As New Akcelerant.Framework.WebControls.Grids.Grid
    With VehicleOptionsGrid
        .ID = "VehicleOptionsGrid"
        .Title = "Vehicle Options"
        .Toolbar.UseDefaultButtons = False        
        .Mode = Grids.Grid.GridMode.Control        
        .Panel.Border = False
        .Panel.Style = "border-width:1px;margin-bottom:5px"
        .Ref = "../../../../../VehicleOptionsGrid"
        .Editable = True
        With .Columns.Add("IsSelected", "Selection", Akcelerant.Framework.WebControls.Grids.Grid.ColumnDataType.Boolean)
            .Renderer = "renderVehicleCheckbox"
        End With
        .Columns.Add("CollateralId", "").Hidden = True
        .Columns.Add("OptionId", "OptionId").Hidden =True         
        .Columns.Add("OptionName", "Name").Width = 200
        .GridHeight = 400
        .DataBind()

        ViewResponse.AddScript(.ToString(False))
        ViewResponse.AddScript("VehicleOptionsGrid.grid.addListener('cellclick', changeOptionStatus);")
    End With
```

Here is where we add the grid to the page:

```
With .AddPanel
                            With .AddPanel
                                .Title = ""
                                .Html = "Standard Options are preselected. Please select additional options as needed."
                                .Style = "padding-bottom:5px"
                            End With
                            .Ref = "../../../../VehicleOptionsPanel"
                            .Title = "Vehicle Options"
                            .Frame = True
                            .Style = "padding-bottom:5px"
                            .Layout = Pages.Panel.LayoutType.Column
                            .Height = 400
                            .Collapsed = True
                            .AddExtObject("VehicleOptionsGrid.grid")
                        End With
```

Comment: Please post your grid config. It seems that the grid sizes are higher than the actual component that holds the grid (a collapsible panel perhaps).

Comment: Added the code that shows where the grid is created and added...

Comment: You were right, it was the grid height...post as an answer and ill give you the check mark ;) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the grid sizes are higher than the actual component that holds the grid (a collapsible panel).